# Is how to setup a dev environment using a specific tool, out of scope?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

My question https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/208143/using-notepad-for-php-coding got closed as being off-topic.

Note that I'm not trying to ask for any tool recommendations or libraries - it is a specific question on how to configure a particular tool for use when programming a certain language.

I'm aware that maybe its off-topic due to a different reason and this one just happened to be the closest fit, would appreciate knowing the actual problem if so.

There are questions on tools that support particular features, is it that I can't ask about a specific tool like Npp but could ask for, say 'Are there good freeware editors support auto completion, syntax highlighting and other features for PHP dev?'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Help Center's page on what is on topic](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) specifically mentions that questions about tools should be asked on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: Somehow I missed that, and only read the part about 'creates debate' elsewhere - thanks.